# Websphere Thread memory monitoring not available with Java Visual VM?

Tags: java, multithreading, websphere, monitoring, jvisualvm

I'm quite surprised that i can't visualize the memory that takes a thread when a java application is deployed on Websphere 8.

I was used to use Java Visual VM to track potential memory leak as in the screenshot below :

[image]

But when i try to use Java Visual VM to track potential memory leak by threads on a application deployed on Websphere 8, this is what I get :

[image]

I spent hours on google to find a way to make it possible with Java Visual VM but I found nothing, so i checked if it was possible with other tools but again I found nothing.

How It can be possible that we can't monitor that ???? If it's the case, Websphere sucks ! But i don't have the choice, my client is using it.

I hope I just didn't search well on internet.

So if someone has a solution, I will be reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeally thankful (exhausted and tired).

tks.

Comment: Visual VM (and Mission Control, etc.) works with the HotSpot JVM. Other than on Solaris and HP-UX, WebSphere Application Server traditional uses the IBM (J9) JVM instead of the HotSpot JVM. Can you confirm which operating system you're on? If so, the general answer to what you're looking for is either a third party profiler or the free [IBM Java Health Center](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/mon-diag-tools?topic=monitoring-diagnostic-tools-health-center) tool which I can provide more details about in an answer once you confirm your OS.